# Bootstrap :Remove navbar brand when on small screen, f.e. mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

The navbar on my website (see code block) expands in height when on mobile (because it doesn't all fit into 1 line).
I noticed that if i delete the brand, it fits. However when on a big screen i would like to keep the brand. How can I make it disappear only for small screens (mobile) and stay for computer screens?

Thank you!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand/logo -->
  <a class="navbar-brand custom-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

i tried adding this to my css but this only cuts off half of my brand to make it fit which i think is uglier than just getting rid of the whole thing.

```
 .custom-brand{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666656/bootstrap-4-responsive-utilities-visible-hidden-xs-sm-lg-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Bootstrap 4.0 documentation: [Hiding elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

> To hide elements simply use the `.d-none` class or one of the `.d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none` classes for any responsive screen variation.
>
> To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one `.d-*-none` class with a `.d-*-*` class, for example `.d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none` will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a class, for example, take desktop as the className and we are using a media query to achieve this. It will now display only on screens that are more than 500px wider.

```html
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
.desktop{
display: none!important;
}
}
</style>

<a class="navbar-brand custom-brand desktop" href="#">Logo</a>
```