# How to make a column span 0 columns on small screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose that I've desktop view of a list of products displayed like in the image below ?

[image]

However, the mobile view doesn't have the purchase buttons on the side. [image]

Is there a way to part these into columns where the column containing the purchase buttons can be hidden for small screens ?

I've tried adding col-sm-0 col-md-4 for the side buttons column, but it didn't work.
the columns stack over each other on small screens.

Comment: Please share your Html code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide one column from grid in bootstrap mobile version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077631/how-to-hide-one-column-from-grid-in-bootstrap-mobile-version)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
`col-sm-12`
```

for example

```
<div class="left col-sm-12 col-md-8">....</div>
<div class="right col-sm-12 col-md-4">....</div>
```

in each column, so that if the screen shrinks each column will create 1 screen block, and the other components drop down